# Why is SKAction.playSoundFileNamed crashing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

NOTE:

It has been a few days and I still am having this problem. One thing that would be helpful, is to know some troubleshooting ideas to try, so I can track down what is causing the crash. Any help that would lead me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

---

I'm running in Xcode 8.2.1 on the simulator, as well as on several different iOS devices. I get the same problem wherever I go.

I have imported a small mp3 file into my spritekit project, called "cat_meow_1.mp3"

when I select the file, in Xcode, and hit the play button, it plays normally. Incidentally I have tried with various different files in various formats, with the same results.

in my code, which complies okay, when I get to the line:

```
run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("cat_meow_1.mp3", waitForCompletion: true))
```

I get a crash with the error message,

> error: use of undeclared identifier '$r0'

Any suggestions how to debug this problem, or to figure out what I did wrong?

I also tried to preload the sound and make a class property, but got the same error. Here's what it looks like:

[image: screenshot of page with error]
[image: screenshot of page with file showing it's in the resource bundle]

UPDATE:

After reinstalling Xcode, I still have the same problem. With certain files, I get white noise, while with other ones I get the error here. What else could be wrong with my system to cause this problem?

UPDATE 2:

tried my experiment on a separate mac, and basically it worked just fine. I reinstalled my OS, and got the same problem, with a little more of an error message this time, which reads:

`2017-01-18 18:10:09.397565 sound attempt 2[533:124220] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2017-01-18 18:10:11.058506 sound attempt 2[533:124042] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2017-01-18 18:10:11.059146 sound attempt 2[533:124042] Metal API Validation Enabled
error: use of undeclared identifier '$r0'
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.`

Comment: to simplify the situation greatly, I created a new Xcode project, type game, spritekit. then i simply dragged a small mp3 file in, and i put the line `run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("filename.mp3", waitForCompletion: true))` into the touchDown function, and got the same exact error.

Comment: Preload sound first. Make a propery and initialize it properly then use it (reuse that action) later in your code. Not saying it will solve this but it may be worth of a try.

Comment: i tried that as well. I got the same crash when I created the pre-load variable as well. I do think I'm using a clean install of Xcode, without any strange extensions.

Comment: Everything works for me. By the way what crash you are talking about?

Comment: i just put in this line: `   private let soundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("cat_meow_1.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
` into the top of GameScene.swift... ok so If i'm getting these errors, what cache files are there to clean out? maybe some corrupted file is messing me up?

Comment: Lol Sorry I mixed up this question with another one that I am currently trying to solve. Ignore my last comment. Will give you a more precise answer when I get my hands on the computer.

Comment: okay. in the meantime, i'll look into what cache files i might try deleting to see if that clears things up for me, then possibly a reinstall of Xcode...

Comment: any info on how i would try to debug such an error would be great, too.

Comment: Make sure you turn off break points if there are any ;) Eg. maybe you forgot about exception break point you have put earlier.

Comment: no break points. i made a whole new file from scratch, and got the same error... getting ready to reinstall xcode.

Comment: I just tried your code on a new project and it works for me.

Comment: i just created an entirely new project again, and a new sound file... that worked for me, kind of. the sound plays as a second of white noise. at least i got something working. not sure what it does not like about the audio files I was using.

Comment: okay. i created a new "game." i went into audacity, recorded me saying "hello," and made an aiff file called "hello.aiff" then I put in the line: `private let soundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("hello.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)` as well as `run(soundAction)` in `touchDown` I got a second of white noise. then i saved as mp3 repeated with mp3 and got same error as i initially got. what the heck is going on lol.

Comment: alright. i reinstalled Xcode. same problem. I do not know what to do.

Comment: I would say your mp3 files are corrupted somehow. Try other file formats. Use wav.

Comment: As Whirlwind has said, and you're beginning to suspect, @DaveKliman, the quality and format of the sound file is incredibly important. You are best off using something like a DAW to export .wav files with the lowest quality you can accept. Or, if you want to be really pedantic, using the .caf converter Apple provides.

Comment: okay, but the first files come from a tutorialhttps://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/how-to-build-a-spritekit-game-in-swift-3-part-2  that has worked for hundreds of others. so i'm suspecting something or other is wrong on my system. I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: i'm beginning to suspect ruby, cocoapds, homebrew, which I recently installed/updated, after getting various errors...

Comment: Yeah, anything to do with Ruby is wrong. Ruby is the new BASIC ;) @DaveKliman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple days, I finally gave in and used *Clean My Mac 3* to completely remove Xcode, as well as any and all related files... I must not have caught everything when previously I uninstalled/reinstalled it, because this time, there were none of my custom settings at all when I ran the reinstalled app.

It works now, thankfully, and I can get back to work.